# Trying to find the appropriate statistical method(s) to answer a marketing question — analyzing composition of groups

Tags: multivariate-analysis, marketing, compositional-data, application

I’ve got roughly 90k rows of data, where each one represents a customer at my company. One of the columns tells me the channel that brought that customer to my company.

I’m looking at the channel mix by quarter (eg, for Q1, x% of customers came from events while y% came from social media). Overall, I’ve got about ten different channels that contribute customers.

What I want to figure out is whether the percentage breakdown changes significantly from quarter to quarter. What method should I use to investigate this?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you would like to understand if there is a change across quarters per channel, of the percentage of clients of your company. I would use a GLM, probably a logistic regression, with an intersection element `company*quarter` and then using a post-hoc approach, such as `emmeans`, to compare quarters per channel. `Emmeans` is a pretty well documented package and have several vignettes, maybe start with this:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/basics.html

Regarding the compositional nature of your data, I think that by using a logistic regression you can address said issue.